# Python Pandas Dataframe: portfolio backtesting investing cashflows on different dates

Tags: python, pandas, portfolio

let's suppose to have the following DataFrame of returns:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web
data = web.DataReader(['AAPL','GOOG'],data_source='google')
returns = data['Close'].pct_change()
```

Now let's say I want to backtest an investment on the two assets, and let also suppose that cashflows are not invested at the same time:

```
positions = {}
positions['APPL'] = {returns.index[10]: 20000.0}
positions['GOOG'] = {returns.index[20]: 80000.0}
wealth = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(positions).reindex(returns.index).fillna(0.0)
```

My question is: is there a pythonic way to let the 20k dollars of positive cashflow on Apple and the 80k dollars on Google grow, based on their respective daily returns?

At the moment I'm doing this iterating by each position (column) and then by i-th row:

```
wealth.ix[i] = wealth.ix[i-1] * (1 + returns[i])
```

but I know that with Python and Pandas this kind of iteration can be often avoided.

Thanks for the time you will spend for this.

[link to iPython Notebook](https://www.wakari.io/sharing/bundle/drsimone/cashflows%20backtesting)

Simone

Comment: Do you want to do a shift: `wealth = wealth.shift() * (1 + returns)`? shift returns your df shifted by 1 so you should be able to do `wealth = wealth.shift() * (1 + returns)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change your position to forward fill, since you keep the investment.

```
pos = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(positions).reindex(returns.index).fillna(method="ffill")
```

Then you need `cumprod`

```
wealth = pos.shift() * (1+returns).cumprod(axis=0)
```

The `shift` is necessary since you do not get the return on the first day.

Comment: I just had to add back the original cashflows:
`wealth = wealth.combineAdd(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(positions))`

thx